# Tab completion not always working for ls command

Tags: command-line, bash, ls, auto-completion

If I stand in my home directory, press `ls` and then press <kbd>Tab</kbd> then I get a list of files. But if I try that with `/etc/elasticsearch` then I don't get a list of files.

Is there some way to achieve what I want or some explanation why it can't be done?

The permissions are

```
root@ubuntu:~# ls -l /etc/|grep lastic
drwxr-s--- 2 root elasticsearch  4096 May 18 09:55 elasticsearch
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your shell doesn’t have the permissions needed to read the files inside this directory. Run a root shell to work around that:

```bsh
$ sudo -i
[sudo] Passwort für dessert: 
root@dessertion:/etc/elasticsearch$ ls # press <TAB>
```